# selenium - node.js - wd test cases

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having a function for my test case, but that get called before the browser get loaded. how to do with that.

```
var browserWin='';

try{
    var browserWin=browser
        .chain()
        .init({
            browserName: 'firefox',
            tags: ["LoginTest"],
            name: "Login Test"
    }) .get(URL+'/main/login')
    .setAsyncScriptTimeout(100000,function(err){
       validatFields(browserWin);
   })

}
catch (err){
     console.error('........Exception..........'+err)
}
```

validatFields get called before the login page get loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in the following way, its coming correctly.

```
var browserWin='';

try{
    var browserWin=browser
        .chain()
        .init({
            browserName: 'firefox',
            tags: ["LoginTest"],
            name: "Login Test"
    }) .get(URL+'/main/login', function(){
       validatFields(browserWin);
   })

}
catch (err){
     console.error('........Exception..........'+err)
}
```

Comment: what is the difference to your answer?

You may want to have a look at https://github.com/admc/wd, too.